# Transform XML-Table to character map

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a table looking like this:

```
<table> 
    <tr>
                    <td>·</td>
                    <td>&amp;#xB7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>É</td>
                    <td>&amp;#xC9</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Î</td>
                    <td>&amp;#xCE</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ú</td>
                    <td>&amp;#xDA</td>
                    </tr>
 </table>
```

I want this table transformed to an xsl:character-map

So for each `<tr>` I need an `<xsl:output-character character="string_in_1st_td" string="string_in_2nd_td"/>`

However, I am failing to compose a working template, please tell me this can be done? :-D

all the best,
K

Edit:
My "best" "not-solution" is this:

```
<xsl:template match="td">
    <xsl:output-character character="@td[position() =1']" string="@td['position()=2')]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I get two errors:

1. An xsl:template element must not contain an xsl:output-character element
2. xsl:output-character may appear only as as a child of xsl:character-map.

Which is helpful, but I need a template that does that, anyways :-D
(unless I want to do this manually for ~500 entries :-D )

Edit2:

Solution:

Alright, so that others may find it:

I have learned something new from Martin Honnen, Thank you very much. You steered me in the right direction :-)

In my case the following did the trick for me:

```
<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    
<xsl:template match="/table/tr">
    <axsl:output-character character="{td[1]}" string="{td[2]};"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I edited this, so that Martin Honnen gets credit, where credit is due!

Comment: So what have you tried and how exactly does it fail? Aren't the second column's values lacking a trailing semicolon `;`?

Comment: The semi-colon doesn't produce an error, this is, after all, only a string. You anticipated what I aim for, I guess ... (have unicodes displayed for stuff I specify in the character-map) 

will update my guesses, as much as I can reproduce them ...

Comment: Are you trying to generate a new XSLT stylesheet (i.e. are you trying to use XSLT to create XSLT)? Or are you trying to build a character map dynamically? Because the latter is not possible.

Comment: And while you're at it, please explain what problem you are *actually* trying to solve. This question very likely is an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and the solution you need is not the solution you're asking about.

Comment: just got back to this now: I want to create an <xsl:character-map> that takes the first td of every <tr> as character="..." and the second td of every <tr> as string=""

Comment: That's not answering any of my questions.

Comment: why not? I told you what I want to happen. So, Answer 1 is on the right track :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a namespace alias https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-namespace-alias if you want to create XSLT code with XSLT, the result elements you want to create have to be in the aliased namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform-alias">

<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>

...
<axsl:output-character character="td[1]" string="td[2]"/>
...
```

Comment: Alright, this works, but I changed the @... part to {@td['position() = ']}" . However, I now get empty character="" and string=""

Comment: Drop the single quotes

Comment: still nothing : https://ibb.co/yqmxCg6 If I leave the curly brackets, I get the string @td[position() =1] as output, which makes sense :-D